# Jquery scrolltop triggering a function between two points?

Tags: jquery, class, scroll, height, pixel

I'm trying to apply a class to a div only when the window top is between 500 and 900 pixels but not before or after. Is this possible?

My current code only works for past 500px:

```
if($(this).scrollTop() >= 500) {
  $('#01').addClass('selected');    
} else {
  $('#01').removeClass('selected');
}
```

Is it possible to have something this?:

```
if($(this).scrollTop() >= 500 <= 900) {
  $('#01').addClass('selected');    
} else {
  $('#01').removeClass('selected');
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var windowPosY = $(this).scrollTop();

if(windowPosY >= 500 && windowPosY <= 900)
{
   //do things
}
```

and I must admit I am curious as to how you checking said position. What event are you binding this logic to?

Comment: Wow, thank you! That works perfectly. I'm using it to highlight a fixed header image when I scroll down to a certain area of the page.

Comment: Then you may accept said answer, and consider the question resolved.

Comment: I will in 8 minutes when I'm allowed to - you were very fast! :)